# Calculate $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^\sqrt2}{(x-1)^\alpha} = l$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I calculate $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exist $l \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^\sqrt2}{(x-1)^\alpha} = l.$$

Comment: For $\alpha=0$ this would be true with limit $l=0$, but that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: @GitGud Edited.

Comment: @user62029 A more eloquent way to formulate the problem would be "Find all $\alpha$ such that the following limit exists finitely."

Comment: Also, I think you want to approach $1$ from above, to avoid fractional powers of negative numbers.

Comment: For any $\alpha$, $\lim_{x\to1}x^\alpha=1$. Am I missing something? Is it, perhaps, $(x-1)^\alpha$ at the denominator?

Comment: does it really depend on $\alpha$? isn't this limit always $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit, as stated, can only be computed for $x\to 1^+$, because $t^{\sqrt{2}}$ is defined only for $t>0$.

Now
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^{\sqrt{2}}}{(x-1)^\alpha}
$$
can be written as
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^{\sqrt{2}}}{(x-1)^\alpha}
\frac{(\sqrt{x}+1)^{\sqrt{2}}}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^{\sqrt{2}}}
=
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt{2}}}{(x-1)^\alpha}
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^{\sqrt{2}}}
$$
and the answer should be clear.

Comment: can't we approach $1$ from left but look only at values that are close enough to $1$ so they are still positive?

Comment: @benji The problem is in $(\sqrt{x}-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ which is *not* defined if $x<1$.

Comment: HA! I missed that... thanks (for some reason I thought you were referring to the $\sqrt{x}$)